# EXCEL - VBA - SQL - Duvida na query usando CAST

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, vba, cast

Olá, Primeiramente peço desculpas ao ADM se houver qualquer erro na formatação da pergunta, sou novato aqui rsrs.

Estou com uma duvida na pesquisa QUERY usando MAX e CAST

**Objetivo:** *Retornar o maior valor na coluna ORDEM forçando-o ser um numero inteiro, onde na coluna LINPRD seja "A"*

**Resultado Esperado:** *5*

**Erro ocorrendo na linha de código =** *RS.Open sql, DB*

Segue minha rotina

```
Sub Pesquisa_SQL_CAST ()
 
Dim DB As New ADODB.Connection 'Variável de Conexão ou Caminho para o banco de dados
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset 'Variável para abrir conexão
Dim sql As String
Dim Final_loop As Integer

With DB
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Data Source") = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1"
        .Mode = adModeRead
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
End With

sql = "SELECT MAX(ORDEM) FROM [Planilha3$A1:B6] WHERE [LINPRD] = 'A' AND CAST(ORDEM AS INTEGER) = '%'"

RS.Open sql, DB

Final_loop = RS(0)

End Sub
```

A tabela na Planilha3$A1:B6 é simplificadamente assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei também usar o Cast assim;

```
sql = "SELECT MAX(CAST(ORDEM AS INTEGER)) FROM [Planilha3$A1:B6] WHERE [LINPRD] = 'A' AND CAST(ORDEM AS INTEGER) = '%'"
```

porém também resulta em erro.

Apenas tenho exito na pesquisa, não utilizando o Cast, desta maneira;

```
sql = "SELECT MAX(ORDEM) FROM [Planilha3$A1:B6] WHERE [LINPRD] = 'A'"
```

Porém gostaria de usar o Cast, para forçar a pesquisa como número INTEIRO, visto que, há a possibilidade de alguma celula na coluna ORDEM estar digitada como TEXTO.

Aproveitando para mais 2 perguntas rsrs.;

1º - Como referenciar uma tabela formatada nomeada ou apenas uma região nomeada no FROM

2º - O CAST e o DISTINCT podem mesmo ser usados na pesquisa SQL pelo VBA, ou devo usar algum correspondente respectivamente.

Obs.: Está habilitado "MICROSOFT ACTIVEX DATA OBJECTS 6.1 LIBRARY" nas "Referências - VBAProject"

Desde já muito obrigado, a todos que puderem ajudar.

------------//------------------------//------------------------//------------------------//------------------------//------------

***Pessoal para aqueles que tiverem o mesmo problema consegui ter uma solução satisfatória;***

**Lógica =** *Faço uma ordenação decrescente convertendo a coluna ORDEM em inteiro atrevés do comando CINT(ORDEM), e trago também em Inteiro*

Segue;

```
sql = "SELECT CInt(ORDEM) FROM [Planilha3$A1:B6] WHERE [LINPRD] = 'A' ORDER BY CInt(ORDEM) DESC"
```

A rotina ficou desta maneira;

```
Sub Pesquisa_SQL_CAST ()
 
Dim DB As New ADODB.Connection 'Variável de Conexão ou Caminho para o banco de dados
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset 'Variável para abrir conexão
Dim sql As String
Dim Final_loop As Integer

With DB
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Data Source") = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1"
        .Mode = adModeRead
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
End With

sql = "SELECT CInt(ORDEM) FROM [Planilha3$A1:B6] WHERE [LINPRD] = 'A' ORDER BY CInt(ORDEM) DESC"

RS.Open sql, DB

Final_loop = RS(0)

End Sub
```

Não consegui utilizar o CAST tive que adaptar usando o CINT, (que pode ser CDBL ou qualquer outro)

Se alguém tiver uma solução melhor ou mais prática, favor compartilhar.

**Ainda não consegui referenciar uma tabela formatada nomeada ou apenas uma região nomeada no FROM**, *quem puder ajudar seria excelente.*

Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: Qual o sentido de você fazer um CAST para integer e comparar o resultado com '%'?

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pelo retorno,

Na verdade a pergunta não é nem essa, fazendo esse mesma Query via SQL padrão, funciona normal, até já testei via o VScode.

Minha maior duvida mesmo seria como ultilizar CAST nessa QUERY via VBA,

Talvez usando o cast desta maneira;

sql = "SELECT MAX(CAST(ORDEM AS INTEGER)) FROM [Planilha3$A1:B6] WHERE [LINPRD] = 'A'

Mas gostaria da ajuda de vcs, para essa questão.

RESUMINDO: "Melhor Maneira de Usar o CAST na Query com MAX."

Desde já obrigado.